# Efficient Use of For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly large excel file (Think  65,000+ rows).

Within the excel file, only two columns matter for this exercise: CCNumber and FileFound (Col BC/BD).

I am trying to use a for loop to loop through the 65,000 + rows and compare the CCNumber (ID) against a folder of files (30,000 files), and then if an id matches/isnt found print "Available" or "Not Found" in the FileFound column - As below:

```vb
Sub LoopFiles
    Dim fileName As Variant, csheet As Variant
    fileName = Dir("Some\Directory\Here\*pdf")

    Dim CCNums As Range
    Set CCNums = Range("BC4:BC68512")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    While fileName <> ""        
        ID = Left(fileName,6) 'id is a 6 digit numeric number, strip away everything else        
        For Each CCNum in CCNums        
            csheet = Left(CCNum, 6)
            if(ID = csheet) Then
                CCNum.Offset(0,1).Value = "Available"
            Else
                CCNum.Offset(0,1).Value = "Not Found"
            End If
        Next CCNum
        fileName = Dir
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above is hilariously inefficient and it takes forever. Is there a way I can speed this up, or am I just going to have to sit here and wait for the spinning wheel of doom to stop.

Comment: You may want to try with PowerQuery uploading your file and the list of files from the folder as tables and perform a  match operation on them instead of looping row by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through a file list you can directly check with `Dir` and wildcards if a file exists.

eg. you can use `Dir("C:\Temp\myNumber*.pdf")` to find a file that is named `myNumberAndUnusefulText.pdf`. So if you use `fileName = Dir("Some\Directory\Here\" & CSheet & "*.pdf")` it will return the file name of a file that starts with the number in `CSheet`.

Further reading all the values into an array first and then processing the array makes your code much faster. Reading and writing actions to cells use a lot of overhead and therefore are slow. By reading the values into an array you reduce it to just one cell reading and one cell writing action.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoopFilesImproved()
    Dim CCNums As Range
    Set CCNums = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BC4:BC68512")  ' always specify in which sheet a range is!
    
    ' define output range
    Dim Output As Range
    Set Output = CCNums.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
    
    ' read output range into array for faster processing
    Dim OutputValues() As Variant
    OutputValues = Output.Value2
    
    ' read all values into an array for faster processing
    Dim CCNumsValues() As Variant
    CCNumsValues = CCNums.Value2
    
    ' loop through numbers and check if a file exists
    Dim iCCNum As Long
    For iCCNum = LBound(CCNumsValues, 1) To UBound(CCNumsValues, 1)
        Dim CSheet As String
        CSheet = Left$(CCNumsValues(iCCNum, 1), 6)
        
        Dim fileName As String
        fileName = Dir("Some\Directory\Here\" & CSheet & "*.pdf")
        
        If fileName <> vbNullString Then
            OutputValues(iCCNum, 1) = "Available"
        Else
            OutputValues(iCCNum, 1) = "Not Found"
        End If
    Next iCCNum
    
    ' write array values back to cell
    Output.Value2 = OutputValues
End Sub
```

Comment: This definitely works, tested it on a few smaller ranges of data ... its just a shame that on my full data set it still takes time (The loop has been running for like half an hour so far) ... i guess thats just the issue you run into when dealing with this much information.

Comment: calling the DIR with the filename each time is slower than what you were doing before. File access is way slower than accessing cells on the sheet, so let the DIR work in the order it finds the files on the disk, and use the Application.Match() function to do a really fast lookup on your worksheet to find the matching cell for the file name. Match() is much faster than iterating over each cell in the range. Also switch off screenupdating too.

Comment: @JoeBourne the solution above worked in two hours, compared to mine that didnt even finish with me leaving it overnight.

Comment: @JoeBourne `Match` might be faster than iterating over cells but not faster than iterating an array once versus a lot of `Match` functions. Which design is actually the fastest cannot be said generally. It highly depends on how your data actually looks like.

Comment: @Krono What you can try is to read all the files into a dictionary first. And then compare the array values against the dictionary. Depending on how your data / files look like this might give it an additional boost. If you have a lot more files than items in your Excel list then this might be slower than the solution above.

Comment: Two hours is super-slow for that approach - are you working with a slow remote/network drive?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try out my approach? how long does it take to run the `FileIds` function?

Comment: @TimWilliams no i did not, but i may use a similar approach to copy said files to relevant folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can try first collecting all of the file names into a dictionary - from that point the check will be fast...

```vb
Sub LoopFiles()
    Dim dictFiles As Object, arrCC, arrAv, rngCC As Range, r As Long
    
    Set dictFiles = FileIds("Some\Directory\Here\*.pdf") 'collect all the file Id's
    
    Set rngCC = ActiveSheet.Range("BC4:BC68512")
    arrCC = rngCC.Value
    ReDim arrAv(1 To UBound(arrCC, 1), 1 To 1) 'size the "available?" array
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrCC, 1)   'loop data from BC
        id = Left(arrCC(r, 1), 6)   'extract the id
        arrAv(r, 1) = IIf(dict.exists(id), "Available", "Not found")
    Next r
    
    rngCC.Offset(0, 1).Value = arrAv  'populate availability in BD

End Sub

'scan all files matching the `folderPath` pattern, and return a Dictionary object
'  with keys equal to the first 6 characters of the file names
Function FileIds(folderPath As String)
    Dim dict As Object, f, id
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    f = Dir(folderPath)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        If Len(f) >= 10 Then dict(Left(f, 6)) = True 'need at least 10 chars with the extension
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    Set FileIds = dict
End Function
```

In a quick test on a local drive with 30k files, calling `FileIds` took about 0.08 seconds.  Calling `Dir()` 65k times on the same folder took 12-13secs.

Answer (score 0):

### Update File Availability Using a List

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateFilesAvailability()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const RightFilePart As String = "*.pdf"
    Const idLen As Long = 6
    Const sRangeAddress As String = "BC4:BC68512"
    Const dCol As String = "BD"
    Const dYes As String = "Available"
    Const dNo As String = "Not found"
    Const Msg As String = "Files availability updated."
    
    ' Validate the folder path.
    Dim fPath As String: fPath = FolderPath
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then fPath = fPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(fPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The folder '" & fPath & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(sRangeAddress)
    
    ' Write the values from the source range
    ' to a 2D one-based one-column array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim cString As String ' Current String
    Dim fName As String ' Current File Name
    Dim r As Long ' Current Array Row
    Dim FileFound As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the destination array and replace its values
    ' with the results.
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        cString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If Len(cString) >= idLen Then
            fName = Dir(fPath & Left(cString, idLen) & RightFilePart)
            If Len(fName) > 0 Then FileFound = True
        End If
        If FileFound Then
            Data(r, 1) = dYes
            FileFound = False
        Else
            Data(r, 1) = dNo
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(dCol)
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.
    drg.Value = Data
    
    'drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    'ws.Parent.Save ' save the workbook
    
    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```